# Error on my onBindViewHolder in Android

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android programming and i cant understand why there is an error on onBindViewHolder implementation of the HomeAdapter class in my project.

```
***This my HomeAdapter.***
```

This my class which i want to use with my recyclerview and cardview.

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
   private Context mContext;
    private List<Products> productsList;


        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView title,count;
            public ImageView thumbnail,overflow;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
                count=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_count);
                thumbnail=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                overflow=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
            }
        }
        public  HomeAdapter(Context mContext,List<Products> productsList){
            this.mContext=mContext;
            this.productsList=productsList;
        }
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_view,parent,false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Products products=productsList.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(products.getName());
            holder.count.setText(products.getNumOfProducts());

            Glide.with(mContext).load(products.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

            holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    showPopUpMenu(holder.overflow);
                }
            });

        }
```

**my custom_view.**
*emphasized text*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/list_item"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#8E00aa"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/list_item"
                    android:id="@+id/list_count"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/overflow"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/navbar"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is the error on onBindViewHolder

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: munene.com.barberbeautyapp, PID: 22033
                                                   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xd
                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:528)
                                                       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4406)
                                                       at munene.com.barberbeautyapp.HomeAdapter.onBindViewHolder(HomeAdapter.java:56)
                                                       at munene.com.barberbeautyapp.HomeAdapter.onBindViewHolder(HomeAdapter.java:23).
```

please asist on this problem

Comment: On which line you getting error? your textview is not found but code is correct. Please show me line on whihc you getting error

Comment: HomeAdapter.java:56 line no 56 of HomeAdapter is? please send 56th line code

Comment: @PETERSON, Will you please highlight your 56th line of code? Where the error actually occur. It's pretty hard to figure out from this massive blocks of codes.

Answer (score 2):

Change this `holder.count.setText(products.getNumOfProducts());` to `holder.count.setText(String.valueOf(products.getNumOfProducts()));`. I guess `products.getNumOfProducts()` returns an `int` value and android is looking for a resource value for that int value and can not find it. So you should give string value.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. Maybe you should mark it correct answer. Thanks ;)